# Calculating color histogram of framebuffer inside compute shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

As the title suggests, I am rendering a scene onto a framebuffer and I am trying to extract the color histogram from that framebuffer inside a compute shader. I am totally new to using compute shaders and the lack of tutorials/examples/keywords has overwhelmed me.

In particular, I am struggling to properly set up the input and output images of the compute shader. Here's what I have:

```
computeShaderProgram = loadComputeShader("test.computeshader");

int bin_size = 1;
int num_bins = 256 / bin_size;
tex_w = 1024;
tex_h = 768;

GLuint renderFBO, renderTexture;
GLuint tex_output;

//defining output image that will contain the histogram
glGenTextures(1, &tex_output);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_output);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16, num_bins, 3, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glBindImageTexture(0, tex_output, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_R16UI);


//defining the framebuffer the scene will be rendered on
glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderFBO);

glGenTextures(1, &renderTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

In the main loop I draw a simple square onto the framebuffer and attempt to pass the framebuffer as input image to the compute shader:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderFBO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glUseProgram(computeShaderProgram);
//use as input the drawn framebuffer
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderFBO);
//use as output a pre-defined texture image
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_output);
//run compute shader
glDispatchCompute((GLuint)tex_w, (GLuint)tex_h, 1);

GLuint *outBuffer = new GLuint[num_bins * 3];
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, outBuffer);
```

Finally, inside the compute shader I have:

```
#version 450
layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;
layout(rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform readonly image2D img_input;
layout(r16ui, binding = 1) uniform writeonly image2D img_output;

void main() {

    // grabbing pixel value from input image  
    vec4 pixel_color = imageLoad(img_input, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy));

    vec3 rgb = round(pixel_color.rgb * 255);

    ivec2 r = ivec2(rgb.r, 0);
    ivec2 g = ivec2(rgb.g, 1);
    ivec2 b = ivec2(rgb.b, 2);

    imageAtomicAdd(img_output, r, 1);
    imageAtomicAdd(img_output, g, 1);
    imageAtomicAdd(img_output, b, 1);
}
```

I defined the output as a 2d texture image of size `N x 3` where `N` is the number of bins and the `3` accounts for the individual color components. Inside the shader I grab a pixel value from the input image, scale it into the `0-255` range and increment the appropriate location in the histogram.

I cannot verify that this works as intended because the compute shader produces compilation errors, namely:

- can't apply layout(r16ui) to image type `"image2D"`
- unable to find compatible overloaded function `"imageAtomicAdd(struct image2D1x16_bindless, ivec2, int)"`
- EDIT: after changing to `r32ui` the previous error now becomes: qualified actual parameter #1 cannot be converted to less qualified parameter ("im")

How can I properly configure my compute shader?
Is my process correct (at least in theory) and if not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your questions:

> can't apply layout(r16ui) to image type "image2D"

`r16ui` can only be applied to unsigned image types, thus you should use `uimage2D`.

> unable to find compatible overloaded function ...

The spec explicitly says that atomic operations can only by applied to 32-bit types (`r32i`, `r32ui`, or `r32f`). Thus you must use a 32-bit texture instead.

---

Your have other issues in your code too.

> ```
> glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderFBO);
> ```

You cannot bind an FBO to a texture. You should instead bind the texture that backs the FBO (`renderTexture`).

Also, you intend to bind a texture to an image uniform rather than a sampler, thus you must use `glBindImageTexture` or `glBindImageTextures` rather than `glBindTexture`. With the later you can bind both images in one call:

```
GLuint images[] = { renderTexture, tex_output };
glBindImageTextures(0, 2, images);
```

Your `img_output` uniform is marked as `writeonly`. However the atomic image functions expect an unqualified uniform. So remove the `writeonly`.

---

You can find all the above information in the OpenGL and GLSL specs, freely accessible from [the OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, these were really helpful comments. I have some problems however. If I am to define the output image as `r32ui`, shouldn't the `internal format` parameter of `glTexImage2D` be `GL_R32` as well? `GL_R32` though does not seem to exist. Finally, changing to a 32-bit type yielded a new error (in place of the previous one), see question edit

Comment: @VlassisFo: the internal format you need is `GL_R32UI`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful :)